# Is this way of fetching data from sqlite correct?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I am using this query to fetch data from sqlite but only one condition is working but not two at same time.

I am also getting some notification that no such column but it exist.

```
String lquery = "SELECT SUM(totalcalorie) AS LTotal FROM fooditem 
WHERE name = ('" + fname + "') AND foodtype = 'Lunch'";
```

Comment: format your question properly

Comment: go to DDMS -> File Explorer -> data -> data -> your package name -> database -> your database
and export it and check you really have that column in there

Comment: yes its there  !
individually they are working

Comment: can you please post this notification that no such column but it exist ?

Comment: there is also no required to use small bracket around fname.

Comment: i removed the bracket now it showing me zero.

Comment: What is the datatype of totalcalorie column in your table.?

Comment: Text is the datatype

Comment: @pratz9999,So there is no recorded found with such where condition.

Comment: but individually is working and data is database. Is my query correct? Should i post screenshot also of database columns?

Comment: try to case Text as int like : SUM(CAST(totalcalorie as int))

Comment: not working this way also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be having null values on those places which you are checking while calling..

go through your code again queries seems write.

Answer (score 0):

change totalcalorie to `INTEGER` type in the database schema

comment says that you are using `TEXT`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152271/sql-query-not-working-while-fetching-data-from-sqlite